# replace a the blanks in a column based on a column c value in R

Tags: r

I have a data set Names as below;

Col A   Col B   Col C

```
            Brook

            Ram

            Sunny

            Mike

            Crook

            David
```

I want to replace the blank in Column B with "Hello Wolrd" for all those column c values with "Brook", "crook", "David".

Any help on this is very much appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
df$colB[df$colB=="" & df$colC %in% c("Brook", "crook", "David")] <- "Hello Wolrd"
```

Comment: one more help what if I want when both ColA and ColB are blanks and then replace Col B values.

Comment: df$colB[df$colB=="" & df$colA==""] <- "Hello Wolrd"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an `ifelse` statement:

```
> df <- data.frame(A = "", B = "", C = c("Brook", "Ram", "Sunny", "Mike", "Crook", "David"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> df
  A B     C
1     Brook
2       Ram
3     Sunny
4      Mike
5     Crook
6     David
> df$B <- ifelse(df$C %in% c("Brook", "Crook", "David"), "Hello World", "")
> df
  A           B     C
1   Hello World Brook
2                 Ram
3               Sunny
4                Mike
5   Hello World Crook
6   Hello World David
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Peter and Cory

Comment: @user3719979 if your question has been answered, you can accept one of the answers to close the question, so that others can see it has been answered